# firebase http function termination and promise

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have the following firebase cloud function

```
exports.sendToUser = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  console.log('start');
  const receiverUid = request.body.receiverId;
  const requestingUid = getUserIdFromRequest(request);

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {       
    "data": {
      "type": request.body.type,
      "mainData": request.body.mainData
    }
  };
  const options = {
    "priority": "high"
  }

  console.log('check');
  requestingUid.then(uid => {
    console.log('complete');
    payload.data.senderId = uid;
    sendMessageToUser(receiverUid, payload, options);
    response.status(200).send();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    response.status(401).send(err);
  });
});
```

My problem with this function is that it prints "start" and "check" all fine but doesn't print the "complete" or the "receiver" nor does it execute the "sendMessageToUser" function. However, the status 200 is responded and the function terminates which I can see in the logs in the developer console and on the client device.

Also, when replacing line `response.status(200).send();` with `response.status(400).send();` or some other response code the correct status (400) is sent but the logs are not printed and the "sendMessageToUser" function not executed.

From time to time, however, the function is properly executed so I'm assuming that the function is somehow prematurely terminated. But how can the correct response code be sent then? I'm aware of the necessity to return a promise from asynchronus functions but as this is a http-triggered (synchronus) function I wouldn't know how to handle this.

Besides, yesterday was the first time this particular error occured. Before that, it worked fine. So can anybody explain what is happening here?

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly what sendMessageToUser does.  If it does any async work, your function code is not correct.

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem. It does indeed some asynchronous work. I'm going to update the function to respond only after all asynchronous work is done. I wasn't aware that responding before that would lead to termination of asynchronous work. Also, I thought I should see the "complete" log in the console which led me down the wrong path here.